# Is Paypal Checkout Client Integration safe for browser?

Tags: php, arrays, paypal

I'm developing a PHP app and I want to use Paypal Checkout Client Integration as a mode of payment for my website. However, the integration requires to put your "client ID" in the script which will totally be exposed on the browser's console. Is it ok to expose your client id to the public?

[screenshot- implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg8Ct.jpg)

Also, the price is in the script as well, what if people will change the price on the fly?

Any advice on this?

Comment: The idea behind combating this: Is your IPN callback URL. You should be verifying the information when IPN posts a payment to your website (Server side), and verify the pricing/other information is correct.

Comment: @FrankerZ does it matter? in the first place, my Client ID is already exposed. I'm not worried if they changed the info but if they can do something to it.

Comment: It matters to validate your data: Absolutely. They can change prices/edit the JS, although your client ID poses little threat. If they change that, they're essentially posting to a different URL which wouldn't do anything harmful.

Comment: @FrankerZ I'm really not worried about changing values for now. Validation is not a problem at this point. I just want to know if a PAYPAL CLIENT ID is ok to expose or not? If not, then client-side integration is a big no-no for a browser app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Client ID is okay to be public, Client SECRET on the other hand must never be placed into anywhere public, that's just for you.

FrankerZ mostly answered this in the comments, the validation that occurs after is the important aspect.

Consider your Client ID like your real life driving license. If someone steals your license they still can't use it as ID to get into a club, the bouncer will just say "That's obviously not you".

In the analogy above PayPal is the bouncer. Your client ID is your driving license and your client secret is your face.

Comment: Finally. So CLIENT ID IS OK TO BE EXPOSED. That's the only "key" they require for the request anyway. Not the SECRET key. 

Validation is easy. no problem about that.

P.S great analogy

Comment: so what do you use the secret key for ? i'm using wordpress and got sick of the paypla plugins not doing exacly what i wanted so I wrote my own plugin which worked perfectly. But only uses the public key. my question is what do i do with the private key ?