# The secret I added to Vercel environment variables shows when I inspect the page

Tags: next.js, paypal-sandbox, vercel

I created a variable called NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID and then created it as a secret on Vercel environment variables but when I inspect the page I can see my client id in plain text. Why is that?

Comment: Environment variables you expose to the browser will be visible in the browser. What was your expectation?

Comment: @juliomalves hrm, my expectation was that it would be obscured since I added it to Vercel as a "Secret". I'm not quite sure how I should go about adding the pay pal keys since it's goes into the html script tag which is on the client side. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you absolutely need it in the client code? Can you not move it to the server, e.g., to an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)?

Comment: I'm using paypal's client-side button: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/ They have an API as well, but I want to figure out if I need to hide the client-id for this specific solution, if that makes sense?

Comment: I think it's fine (and expected?) to have the Client ID publicly visible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52852769/1870780

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, I didn't see that question when I searched it up ^ do you want to add that as an answer below so I can accept it as the answer to this problem?